# "Root file system not defined. Please correct this from partitioning menu" Ubuntu 14.04.2 installation on laptop with no OS

Tags: usb-installation

So I'm new to linux I have a laptop that didn't have and OS so I thought I'd install Ubuntu rather than go out and buy windows. Well anyways I got a LiveUSB and tried to install. Now when I got to the installation type screen it is blank and when I press Install now it says "Root file system not defined. Please correct this from partitioning menu" and if I press any other button it freezes and won't let me press any other buttons. I can't find anything that explains what I need to do to correct this. I have and Acer Aspire 9410-5933.

Answer (score 1):

To be installed, `Ubuntu` needs a `root` partition in which to copy the kernel along with all the programs included, the additional / third-party software and the files required for everything to work. This is usually the "primary" (and biggest) partition, so that it's possible to hold additional software added during the regular use of the system, altough this is not mandatory. You need to specify to the installer which partition is to be used as the `root` partition, by specifying one and one only `root` mount point (`/`):

1. Click "`Add...`" to add your "primary" `root` partition

[image: Installation type step]

2. Specify the "`Size`" of the partition, set the partition as "`Primary`", set its location to be at the "`Beginning of the space`", set it to be used as "`Ext4 journaling file system`" and set its "`Mount point`" to be "`/`", then click "`Ok`"

[image: Installation type step - 2]

3. Click "`Install now`"

Comment: This answer should have been accepted by the OP.